# How can i put photo with effect on static video fragment?

Tags: python, video, video-processing

I need to make a script that will use video template and combine it with user photos to create personal New Year greeting. 
As a result i need something like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=292&v=mi3IHAJ4kIg
Which approach i can use to create something like this?

Comment: `Which approach i can use to create something like this?` Depends. We don't know what tools you have for this task... Most professionals would use something like Adobe's After Effects (expensive) to create a template with two layers (for photo and animated background). Template is just an XML file which is later updated by changing image paths to change "user" photo for each new video.

Comment: PS: Another option is the free FFmpeg. Use it to encode video outputs. For inputs you can use its options to overlay an image above the video (animated background animation). Can you work with pixels/canvas in Python? Can you use byte arrays? Can you use `standard` input/output? What known skills and tools do you have towards solving _any_ part of this task?